# Adding 'if' conditions to jquery .show function

Tags: jquery, onclick, hide, show

In jquery, I would like to show the div '**hidden_div**' when the submit button '**input#download-submit**' is clicked but only when the div '**div.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok**' is visible on the page.

So far, I have the code to make hidden_div show when the input#download-submit button is clicked - but i'm not sure how to add if conditions?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#download-submit").click(function(){
        $(".hidden_div").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides pseudo selector `:visible` that you can use along with `is()` which returns a boolean.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#download-submit").click(function(){
        if( $('div.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok').is(':visible') ){
            $(".hidden_div").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Reference: [is() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:

```
$("input#download-submit").click(function(){
    if ($('div.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok').is(":visible"))
        $(".hidden_div").show();
});
```

I have posted a fiddle with a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sx9mm7mn/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#download-submit").click(function(){
      if($('.when_visible').is(':visible')) {
            $(".hidden_div").show();
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">       </script>
    </head>
    <div class="hidden_div" style='display:none'>hidden test</div>
    <div class="when_visible">visible</div>
    <input type="button" id="download-submit" value="submit when visible"/>
  </body>
</html>
```